# Does anyone know this issue in "xcode console"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

As I remembered, i had make somthing config in my project, but i forgot how to remove nor add(or open) it. Here is my xcode's console logs me:

```
 <CFBasicHash 0x7fef63d33a30 [0x111a25180]>{type = mutable dict, count = 25,
entries =>
1 : <CFString 0x7fef63d31db0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleName"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32ec0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "KTVGroupBuy"}
2 : <CFString 0x7fef63d31f50 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "DTSDKName"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32e90 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "iphonesimulator8.4"}
3 : <CFString 0x1119fdb40 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoPlistURL"} = <CFURL 0x7fef63d32bd0 [0x111a25180]>{string = Info.plist, encoding = 134217984
base = <CFURL 0x7fef63d322f0 [0x111a25180]>{string = file:///Users/Apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A5CE7D85-380C-434E-A075-E750F5397B4E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CCF770CD-2865-4008-A45A-B12A09092728/KTVGroupBuy.app/, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}}
4 : <CFString 0x1119fdb80 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleNumericVersion"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000010080002 [0x111a25180]>{value = +16809984, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
5 : <CFString 0x7fef63d328d0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UILaunchStoryboardName"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32ee0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "LaunchScreen"}
11 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32900 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32f00 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "en"}
12 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32ac0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleVersion"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32f20 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "1"}
14 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32af0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"} = <CFBasicHash 0x7fef63d33060 [0x111a25180]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32f40 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UINavigationBar"} = <CFBasicHash 0x7fef63d32fe0 [0x111a25180]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32f70 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "Style"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d32fb0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UIBarStyleDefault"}
1 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32f90 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "Translucent"} = <CFBoolean 0x111a25c00 [0x111a25180]>{value = false}
}

}

15 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32b20 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UIStatusBarStyle"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d330e0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent"}
16 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32c20 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d33150 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "APPL"}
17 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32b80 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "UIMainStoryboardFile"} = <CFString 0x7fef63d33130 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "Main"}
18 : <CFString 0x7fef63d32c50 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"} = <CFArray 0x7fef63d331d0 [0x111a25180]>{type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (
0 : <CFString 0x7fef63d331a0 [0x111a25180]>{contents = "iPhoneSimulator"}
...
...
```

Is there anyone knows how to remove or close these logs? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i find where it logs me these. I had this code in my codes:

```
 CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)(infoDictionary));
```

And when i remove it, it runs OK.